# My PHP page is not saving data

Tags: php, mysql, store

I'm new in PHP programming and I'm trying to create a PHP page that has a box to write a text, for example, store this information and exhibit it. The ideia is the user is going to write the text in the box and when the click to "Send" the MySQL will store the information in the table and the command "atualizaPagina()" will show the information added.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php

    require_once("enviar.php");

    if(!empty($_POST)){
        gravaTopico($_POST["mensagem"]);
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Teste em php</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

            atualizaPagina();
        ?>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
            <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="mensagem"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the enviar.php file is here

```
<?php

    function gravaTopico($values){

        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "Alabra%$") or die(mysql_error());

        mysql_select_db("ifscjr") or die(mysql_error());

        $strSQL = "INSERT INTO topicos(comentarios) VALUES($values)";

        mysql_query($strSQL) or die (mysql_error());

        mysql_close();
    }

    function atualizaPagina(){

        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "Alabra%$") or die(mysql_error());

        mysql_select_db("ifscjr") or die(mysql_error());

        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM topicos";

        $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
            echo $row['comentarios'] . "<br />";
        }

        mysql_close();
    }

?>
```

Comment: can you elaborate what error are you getting????

Comment: That looks quite ok ; do you have any error message written where you are expecting the result of atualizaPagina ?

Comment: did you checked your database table if values are saved there...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO topicos(comentarios) VALUES ('$values')";
```

Answer (score 0):

MuthaFury is right.
 But, also you need to check not only that $_POST ins not empty, you need to check that $_POST["mensagem"] exists (!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST["mensagem"])).
And you need to escape input string from quotes using mysql_real_escape_string, because if your $_POST["mensagem"] wiil contain quote (') your sql will be broken.
Example for your code:

```
$values = mysql_real_escape_string($values);
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO topicos(comentarios) VALUES('$values')";
```

Comment: I'll try this later! Thank you also! Thanks